# Rolling count specific number

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have dataframe "df" like this

| Time | Group | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 00:05:00 | A | 0 |
| 2022-10-01 00:10:00 | A | 0 |
| 2022-10-01 00:15:00 | A | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 00:20:00 | A | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 00:25:00 | A | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 00:30:00 | A | 0 |
| 2022-10-01 00:35:00 | A | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 00:40:00 | A | 0 |
| 2022-10-01 00:05:00 | B | 11 |
| 2022-10-01 00:10:00 | B | 0 |
| 2022-10-01 00:15:00 | B | 12 |
| 2022-10-01 00:20:00 | B | 13 |
| 2022-10-01 00:25:00 | B | 0 |
| 2022-10-01 00:30:00 | B | 0 |
| 2022-10-01 00:35:00 | B | 15 |
| 2022-10-01 00:40:00 | B | 16 |

Assume That I already sort out data by Group and Time already
I would love to count occurence of  0 in previous 15 minutes include itself

Which result should be like

| Time | Group | Data | Count_0_last_15_min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 00:05:00 | A | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 00:10:00 | A | 0 | 2 |
| 2022-10-01 00:15:00 | A | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-10-01 00:20:00 | A | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 00:25:00 | A | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-10-01 00:30:00 | A | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 00:35:00 | A | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 00:40:00 | A | 0 | 2 |
| 2022-10-01 00:05:00 | B | 11 | 0 |
| 2022-10-01 00:10:00 | B | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 00:15:00 | B | 12 | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 00:20:00 | B | 13 | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 00:25:00 | B | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 00:30:00 | B | 0 | 2 |
| 2022-10-01 00:35:00 | B | 0 | 3 |
| 2022-10-01 00:40:00 | B | 16 | 2 |

currently I try to use rolling to get data from each from previous record

```
df.groupby('Group')['Data'].rolling(3,min_periods=1)
```

however I stuck after rolling part to only counting "0" occurrence ( I did try .eq(0).sum() but it can't apply with  rolling() method

is there another method to group by and rolling count for this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
(df.assign(Count_0_last_15_min=df['Data'].eq(0))
   .groupby('Group', as_index=False)
   .rolling(3, min_periods=1)['Count_0_last_15_min'].sum()
   .droplevel(0)
)
```

Output:

```
0     1.0
1     2.0
2     2.0
3     1.0
4     0.0
5     1.0
6     1.0
7     2.0
8     0.0
9     1.0
10    1.0
11    1.0
12    1.0
13    2.0
14    2.0
15    1.0
Name: Count_0_last_15_min, dtype: float64
```